# How to deserialize this JSON to a List?

Tags: c#, json, list, api, deserialization

I have an issue with deserializing the JSON file from the web to a `List`.

My code is down below, but it does not execute and shows `System.NullReferenceException`. It happens in the `Content()` method, when I call `callApiAsync()` in the List.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Content();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async static void Content()
    {
        List<Coin> coins = await callApiAsync();

        for (int i = 0; i < coins.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(coins[i].price);
        }
    }

    static async Task<List<Coin>> callApiAsync()
    {
        string url = "https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/charts?period=all&coinId=bitcoin";

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        string jsonResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonResponse);
        return data.coins;
    }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Coin> coins { get; set; }
}

public class Coin
{
    public int time { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

My JSON for example:

```json
{
   "chart":[
      [
         1372032000,
         107.979,
         1,
         0
      ],
      [
         1372118400,
         102.982,
         1,
         0
      ],
      [
         1372204800,
         103.34,
         1,
         0
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: What JSON? Please include all relevant information (such as an example of the JSON that would make your code a [mre]) in your question. It should not be necessary to visit an external website to understand your question. Please also include all the details of the error, such as what line it occurs on.

Comment: Note that just hard-coding the JSON in a minimal console app (or loading it from a file) would make this easier to reproduce. The fact that your JSON doesn't have any properties in common with your code is somewhat alarming though...

Answer (score 2):

The sample JSON you gave:

```
{"chart":[[1372032000,107.979,1,0],[1372118400,102.982,1,0],[1372204800,103.34,1,0]]}
```

Does not have a type that matches the "Root" class you are trying to deserialize to.

You can paste your JSON into a site like https://json2csharp.com/ to find out what the corresponding C# class should look like. In this case, the `Root` class should look like the following to support deserializing the specified JSON:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<List<double>> chart { get; set; }
}
```

My guess is that you then intend to *interpret* the first value in each list as some sort of time stamp, the second value as a "price", and ignore the second and third values in each list. You will have to do the legwork for this after first deserializing the JSON to a list of lists of doubles.

For example:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonResponse);
return data.chart.Select(listOfDoubles => new Coin
{
    time = (int)listOfDoubles[0],
    price = listOfDoubles[1]
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Adding in that if that Time is meant to be a unix timestamp then they can make the property have a `DateTime` typing and use `time = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(listOfDoubles[0]).UtcDateTime.ToLocalTime();`

Comment: Thank you, but still have a problem because I have "Cannot convert type 'programname.Coin to int' error message".

Comment: @vajuakos To simplify your own troubleshooting, I suggest completely commenting out the `Coin` class and all references to it until you've solved the deserialization issue (which does not make use of the `Coin` class). Once you have successfully deserialized to the `Root` class, and your program is compiling and running successfully, you can move on to subsequent issues pertaining to converting your `Root` class to a list of `Coin` classes.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one string of code to deserialize

```
return JObject.Parse(jsonResponse)["chart"]
.Select(x => new Coin { time = UnixSecondsToDateTime( (long) x[0]), 
                        price = (decimal)x[1] }
        ).ToList();


public class Coin
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}

public static DateTime UnixSecondsToDateTime(long timestamp, bool local = false)
{
    var offset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp);
    return local ? offset.LocalDateTime : offset.UtcDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API documentations do not tell anything about the response ([1](https://cryptocointracker.com/api/coinstats/get/public-v1-charts), [2](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5734027/RzZ6Hzr3)).

So, if we can assume that the first number represents an epoch timestamp and the second the average price then you can parse the response with Linq2Json like this

```
var chart = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse)["chart"] as JArray;
List<(int Time, int Price)> coins = new();
foreach (JArray coin in chart)
{
    coins.Add(((int)coin[0], (int)coin[1]));
}
```